# How to configure deep-linking in iOS with Firebase Dynamic Links?

Tags: ios, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm trying to configure Firebase Dynamic Links into my iOS project and I'm having trouble interpreting the [documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually?authuser=1) and how it needs to be adapted to my specific scenario.

In particular, when creating a deep link manually, I don't know what I should put instead of `your_deep_link` in the following example:

```
https://your_subdomain.page.link/?link=your_deep_link&apn=package_name[&amv=minimum_version][&afl=fallback_link]
```

They say it should be `http` or `https`, so I used a generic https website URL for the marketing page of my app. But then in XCode, in [this doc there](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive?authuser=1) they say:

> In the Info tab of your app's Xcode project, create a new URL type to
>   be used for Dynamic Links. Set the Identifier field to a unique value
>   and the URL scheme field to be your bundle identifier, which is the
>   default URL scheme used by Dynamic Links.

So nowhere do I specify that my app should be open instead of the marketing website when loading on a device where the app is already installed. And I think that's why when I try to open this link in my iPhone's browser, it just loads the page there in the browser:

```
https://debugapproofreferences.page.link/?link=https%3A%2F%2Fapproof.derbigum.com%2Freferences%2Fleads%2F5b98ca7a-18f7-4ffa-8dbe-aed51b94f18b&apn=com.derbigum.approofreferences&ibi=com.derbigum.ApproofReferences&isi=1321450315
```

Note that I have 3 variants of the same app depending on the environment (Debug, Beta, Prod), so associated domain is set to `applinks:$(DEEP_LINKS_DOMAIN)`, and `DEEP_LINKS_DOMAIN` is a user-defined setting depending on the environment, and for the Debug environment I'm working on right now, `DEEP_LINKS_DOMAIN=debugapproofreferences.page.link`.

Obviously I'm missing something here, and it's the first time I ever try to configure deep links so I'm a little lost.

Comment: Have you figured out deep link?

Comment: No I have not figured it out yet.

Comment: Have you done this part? https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/ios/receive?authuser=1

Comment: I have done before but not using firebase it simple my domain like `www.mydomain.com`

Comment: @DisableR yes, I have